# Convert .htaccess to Nginx - current re_rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

Being all new to Nginx (im really a rookie) I just found out that my .htaccess url rewrites doesnt work with Nginx.

I found some converter here:
http://winginx.com/htaccess

I tried converting my .htaccess there, but after integrating i nmy .conf ended up in a weird result of some url prompting to download when clicking them etc.

Perhaps i've misunderstood on how to integrate it, but what ive done is defining it in the .conf for my specific site, which is:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.conf

My original .htaccess looks as the following:

```
#php_value arg_separator.output &amp;

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain.com\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ picture-normal.php?pic=$2 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/(.*)$ ./$3 [L]

#RewriteRule ^[^/]/([0-9]*) test.html?id=$1

#RewriteRule ^set([0-9]*)-Assorted_Images_([0-9\-]*).html set.php?id=$1
#RewriteRule ^Funny-(.*)-([0-9]*).html jokes.php?id=$2
#RewriteRule ^Funny-(.*)-([0-9]*)-page([0-9]*).html jokes.php?id=$2&page=$3
#RewriteRule ^funny-joke-([0-9]*)-(.*).html joke.php?id=$1

#RewriteRule ^(.*).html index.php?p=$1
```

Which converted to:

```
    # nginx configuration

    location / {
      if ($http_host !~ "^www\.mydomain\.com$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 redirect;
      }
      rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 break;
      rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /picture-normal.php?pic=$2 break;
    }
```

The whole .conf looks like this: /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.conf :

```
server
{
    server_name .mydomain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht
    {
        deny all;
    }

    # nginx configuration

    location / {
      if ($http_host !~ "^www\.mydomain\.com$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 redirect;
      }
      rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 break;
      rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /picture-normal.php?pic=$2 break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do have PHP fastcgi set up correctly, this should work for you.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return       301 http://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    # Are you sure you have this set up?
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # nginx configuration
    location / {
        rewrite ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 last;
        rewrite ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ picture-normal.php?pic=$2 last;
    }
}
```

The main difference is doing the mydomain to www.mydomain redirection in a separate server block which is more effective and replacing the "breaks" with "last" which, if PHP fastcgi is properly setup, will fix the download issue.

Comment: EDIT: Hi Dayo,

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my issue - it is truly appreciated.

I tried implementing your suggestion,

Comment: EDIT EDIT:
EDIT: Hi Dayo,

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my issue - it is truly appreciated.

I tried implementing your suggestion and had two different results.
Result 1 - when implementing all of your suggested code and restarting nginx service, I got a an error message: "nginx: [warn] conflicting server name ".mydomain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored" = Requesting the site domain, I just got the default nginx welcome page.......

Comment: Results 2 - I removed the first "server { listen: ....." block - - restarted the service and the site worked again. Clicking the menu link that before gave me the download request, now just leads me to a "404 Not Found. nginx/1.2.4" page.

The fastcgi was just some part of the .conf which came from a tutorial, so thought it was default - so dont think i got that :/

Comment: Both server blocks are needed. Note that the example in your question is wrong. you use `server_name .mydomain.com;`. It should be `server_name mydomain.com;`. So just copy the code I gave and replace `mydomain` with your real domain name. On the fastcgi bit, that is a separate issue. You need to look up info on how to set up PHP for nginx. You can use fastcgi or proxy to apache. There are examples for fastcgi here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI. That is a whole new kettle of fish I'm afraid.